# How is the aircraft stand vertical lux measured?

Tags: airport-lighting

How is the vertical lux measurements taken for aircraft stands? Is it 2 m above the ground with the lux meter facing the light source, or parallel to the centreline?

What is the purpose of the lights on the stand? Is it for the ground services or the aircraft?

Answer (score 2):

In 2m height, from two sides minimum, best if they are perpendicular to the centerline

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/46395)

Comment: @Sean It actually does provide an answer to the question. Peter, welcome to Aviation.SE! It sounds like you have personal experience with these measurements. Could you expand your answer a bit and maybe include a reference?

Comment: Hi and welcome to aviation.SE. Don't hesitate to check the [help center](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) to @Bianfable 's comment about answer expansion.